# Adding custom description meta tag in wordpress pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have a question about wordpress pagination query.

For example; When i click the second page domain.tld/page/2 how to change the page's description meta in `wp_head();` is there any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've searched the answer and have not found right solution.
Check this out

```
function add_meta_tags_for_pagination_pages() {
    global $page, $wp_query; // need to use globag vars in function
    if ( is_paged() ) { // it is a pagination
        $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; // get current pagination page

        if (!is_home()){ // it is pagination in some category
            $category = get_the_category($wp_query->posts[0]->ID);
            $category_name = $category[0]->name;
        }  

        echo '<meta name="description" content="' . (isset($category_name) ? $category_name . ' | ' : '') . sprintf( __( 'Page %s' ), $paged ) . '" />' . "\n";
        echo '<meta name="keywords" content="' . (isset($category_name) ? $category_name . ', ' : '') . sprintf( __( 'Page %s' ), $paged ) . '" />' . "\n";
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_meta_tags_for_pagination_pages' , 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer still works.  Just adding get_the-excerpt() would be a better page description.

Also, the solution is not working on pages with a /category sub directory

Comment: What version  of WP have you tested this code in. Quality would be improved if you explain how/why it works - the logic behind it. Code only answers are  discouraged on SO, and are much less likely to be upvoted. Generally, answers should be tested -- without that, it borders on a suggestion/Comment territory.  However some questions don't give enough source code or context to do so.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for this ?

```
remove_action ('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
```

Comment: explaining how this would help would help?